# CDF of t distribution in terms of CDF with smaller degrees of freedom

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

It is possible to write the PDF of t distribution with $\nu+1$ degrees of freedom in terms of PDF with $\nu-1$ degrees of freedom:
$$
t_{\nu+1}(x) = \sqrt{\frac{\nu-1}{\nu+1}}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{\nu+2}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{\nu-1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{\nu+1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{\nu}{2}\right)}\left(1+\frac{x^2}{\nu+1}\right)^{-1}t_{\nu-1}\left(x\sqrt{\frac{(\nu-1)}{\nu+1}}\right)
$$ 
But how to do the same thing for CDF? In other words, how to write $T_{\nu+1}$ in terms of $T_{\nu-1}$ (or $T_{\nu-1}$ in terms of $T_{\nu+1}$)?

Comment: Actually, I was able to show that $$\frac{T_{\nu+1}(a\sqrt{\nu+1})}{T_{\nu-1}(a\sqrt{\nu-1})}\frac{\nu}{\nu-1}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{\nu+1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{\nu}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{\nu+2}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{\nu-1}{2}\right)}-\frac{a}{\sqrt{\nu-1}}\frac{t_{\nu-1}(a\sqrt{\nu-1})}{T_{\nu-1}(a\sqrt{\nu-1})}=1$$. Now the question is how to prove this?

Comment: It's assumed that $$a \in \mathbb R, \nu>2$$.